# Countdown (Cookies)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

How do I make this countdown able to not reset the countdown when it is refresh? Like when I click refresh it should continue the countdown instead of resetting the countdown again, from "14d, 22h, 23m, 32s" (refresh) to continue to "14d , 22, 59m, 59s".

With some research I saw I should use Cookies but I don't know how to create one, hope you can help me create one!

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans';

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ps';
    src: url("../fonts/personalservice.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'afb';
    src: url("../fonts/Agency_FB.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'blob';
    src: url("../fonts/Blobtastics.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'rv';
    src: url("../fonts/roundedvale.ttf");
}

/*start loading*/

.spinner{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    
    border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:3px solid #f25a41;
    border-radius: 100%;
    
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#overlay{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  opacity: .5;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    color: #67727A;
    font-family: 'Alegreya', Sans-serif;
}


#banner{
    height: 592px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#branding{
    padding-top: 150px;
    width: 752px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 400px;
}

#text{
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'ps';
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 251px;
    height: 90px;
    background: url(../img/RH5.png) no-repeat center;
}

#clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 440px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}


footer{
    background-color: #87ceeb;
    height: 70px;
}

#ig img{
    width: 49px;
    height: 49px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    text-align: center;
}

#fb img{
    width: 49px;
    height: 49px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 625px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="FSX Repaints">
    <meta name="keywords" content="fsx, repaints, project airbus, just flight, pmdg, captainsim, premier airraft design, pad, airlines, project opensky, posky, tom's ruth">
    <meta name="author" content="Raven Lescano">
    <title>Coming Soon | Raven's Hangar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/countdown.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <body>
        <section id="banner">
            <div id="branding">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="img/RH5.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <aside id="text">
                    <p>coming soon</p>
                </aside>
            </div>

            <div id="clockdiv">
                <div>
                    <span class="days"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="hours"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="minutes"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="seconds"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <!--End Banner-->
        <footer>
            <div id="fb">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ravenshangar"><img src="img/fb.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div id="ig">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ravens_hangar/"><img src="img/ig.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!--End of Footer-->
    </body>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/countdown.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using cookies I would save the data in local storage, as it is much more convenient compared to cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java script you can use window.localstorage

so Update your code.

**From :**

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

**To :**

```
var deadline;
if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('deadline')){
deadline = window.localStorage.getItem('deadline');
} else {
  deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  window.localStorage.setItem('deadline',deadline);
}
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: so I need to make a local storage?

Comment: cookie and localStorage these are 2 ways posible in your case.

Comment: in above code we just check on every page refresh if ur local storage has deadline then we init our time with localstorage time otherwise we create new deadline and store into localstorage. if you satisfy with the ans please upvote it.. thanx

Comment: Thanks it worked, when I refresh the tab it still display the current/left time!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link to see how to create cookie in Javascript :
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp